# Page Redirection in Lightning Based on Profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have these Lightning Component wherein What I need to do is put a condition on which it should redirect.

wherein for example. if System Administrator then proceed to google.com while if Non-System Administrator it should go to yahoo.com, can you help me build that certain lightning component that will based on profile the url it will open?

```
onInit : function(component, event, helper){
var acctd = component.get("v.recordId");
var urlString = $A.get("$Label.c.ExternalPage");
console.log(urlString);
window.open(urlString+'/PageExternal?id='+acctd,'_blank',
             'height=700,width=1200, resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:-

Here is the Component where I am defined the aura: handler to redirect you to the URL based on profile:-

```
<aura:component controller="currentUserInfoCtrl" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

In JavaScript Controller, I am calling my apex method and getting the response as profile detail. After that, I am executing the window.open to redirect based on the profile name.

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.fetchUser");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                if(storeResponse.Name="System Administrator"){
                    window.open('https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232300/page-redirection-in-lightning-based-on-profile',
                                'height=700,width=1200, resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no');
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

In apex method, I querying the user record and later the profile and returning it to the client side controller:-

```
public with sharing class currentUserInfoCtrl {
   @AuraEnabled 
    public static Profile fetchUser(){
     // query current user information  
      User oUser = [select id,Name,TimeZoneSidKey,Username,Alias,Country,Email,FirstName,LastName,IsActive,IsPortalEnabled,ProfileId 
                 FROM User Where id =: userInfo.getUserId()];
        Profile p =[select id, Name from Profile where id=:oUser.ProfileId];
        return p;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps You.

Comment: thank you so much Sanket Kumar! Finally it worked! since I have certain conditions also in page redirection in a visualforce page that's why i need to create a lightning component to also use in community! thanks so much!

Comment: @Cloud Welcome :)